# Windows eating up all disk space

Tags: windows-10, ssd, disk-space

I have 118GB + 14GB backup SSD. The problem is that Windows folder alone is 64GB big + Users 10.5GB + SWSETUP 8GB. You can imagine I am running of the space fast. Is this normal?

Answer (score 2):

Regrettably, Windows uses a *lot* of disk space, and the amount grows over time. It is possible to [use DISM to eliminate some of the update files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder?view=windows-11), **at the risk of preventing a rollback should an update be harmful**.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type *cmd*.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and confirm the UAC dialog, to get a CMD prompt as Administrator.
- Enter the following:

  ```
  Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase
  ```
- After that completes, enter the following:

  ```
  Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /SPSuperseded
  ```

If all else fails, consider getting a larger SSD, or try an alternative OS. My experience has been that [Ubuntu](https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-system-requirements), for example, runs happily using less than 25 GB of storage with default apps including LibreOffice Suite, Firefox and Thunderbird *on the same partition*.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the biggest eaters in `C:\Windows` are the following folders,
which cannot be reduced:

- `C:\Windows\WinSxS`
- `C:\Windows\Installer`

The following folders can be cleaned up of most of their files:

- `C:\Windows\Temp`
- `C:\Users\USER-NAME\Downloads`

The best way to clean up the `C:` disk is to right-click it in Explorer
and select Properties. In the General tab, click the button of
"Disk Clean-up".
You will see a list of items that can be deleted. Select and click
"Clean up system f‌iles".

If the liberated space is not enough, a bigger `C:` disk will be
the best solution.

Other disk-saving operations you can do:

- [Disable Hibernate](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-enable-disable-hibernate-windows-10-a.html)
  will remove the large `C:\hiberfil.sys`
- [Minimizing the Virtual Memory Pagefile](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/77692-manage-virtual-memory-pagefile-windows-10-a.html)
  will reduce the large `C:\pagefile.sys`.

Note: To see the above two files you will need to enable the
viewing of hidden files.

Comment: According to Microsoft's own docs, you can [reduce the size of the WinSxS folder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder?view=windows-10), although my experience is that it still ends up being quite large.

Comment: This: C:\Windows\Installer how can I reduce its size? It has over 30GB.

Comment: The `Installer` folder is used in order to uninstall applications. You can delete it, but then you won't be able to uninstall any installed application (not recommended). Disk Clean-up is the only tool that can safely touch it. I added to my answer a couple more methods that can gain gigabytes.

Comment: @Dom - Uninstalling software you don’t need.

Comment: As I said. Sadly there is not any software on C: despite that still being full. And I am cleaning disks regularly.

Comment: Can I move C:\Windows\Installer to D: and then just put it back if I need to uninstall something?

Comment: The last additions to my answer can help without taking chances with Windows.